# How to read <connectionstring> of web.config from a console application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-config, connection-string, app-config

I have VB.net console application. I would like to read the (ConnectionString) from a web.config.

`Web.config` is located at a particular path in my virtual PC, say **"C:/mywebConfig"**

```
<add name="MY_DB" connectionString="Data Source=DATASOURCE;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist 

Security Info=False; User ID=***;Password=****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My code:

```
Dim connString As String = String.Empty

connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MY_DB").ConnectionString
```

Whenever I try to access it, i get the error not set to an instance of an object or something like that :)

Help please.

I tried to add the web.config in my Project, but still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt suggested for a console app you need to include a app.config file instead. For easy reading of that file you can reference the System.Configuration assembly and then use the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings property.

For example:

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

**EDIT**

I've just re-read your post and it might be a good idea to check your app has permission to read .config files from the c:\ drive.

Answer (score 2):

If you do indeed want to read the `app.config` or `web.config` of *another* (web) app, take a look at [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`web.config` is used for web applications - you will need a `app.config` file.

Have a look at this link for the differences:

[dotNET - app.config and web.config](http://win.cyberactiva.com/dettaglio.asp?id=356)

Also this stack overflow question [what is app.config for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431742/what-is-app-config-for)