# how to load a form only at the first time after program is installed

Tags: c#

My speech recognition project include 2 forms form1 & form2. Form2 is my main form but before loading form2 my program take a variable value from user through form1 and pass it to form2. It means at start my program opens form1 takes value & pass it to form2 then form2 is shown.
Now my question is how to 
make form1 load only at programs 1st launch after installation and after 1st launch directly form2 is loaded thereafter?
means form1 should not be loaded after that..

Comment: you can store a value in your application configuration and override it after the first time...`if(appConfigFirstStartValue==true){//show form....appConfigFirstStartValue = false;}`

Comment: Are the "variables" from form1 stored anywhere? Like in a file, the registry or a database?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin no the variables are not stored anywhere.the variable is implicitly created & then passed via get & set method

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I didn't got it can you please provide me with details?

Comment: But you still need to pass that original value to form2. Right?

Comment: I guess getting the values for form2 is not your issue but just ensuring that form1 is only executed once, sorry I cannot write up a "real" answer now, but here is a link as to how you can handle app.configs, in essence you write the default app.config(shipped with your installation) manually and include it and then read and write to it later on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13043569/2186023

Comment: @Steve yes i want to pass that variable value assigned to it in its 1st attempt

Comment: @user3289174 you can write those values you grab from your 1st form into the app.config also (and i guess you should ;))

Comment: Then you need to store it in some file and retrieve before starting the first form

Comment: @Steve thank you buddy can you give me a basic overview program of this?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste thank you sir..i will study it from your mentioned link

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a simple textfile where you could store the input value recorded the first time your app starts, then, check if the file with the value exists and read it back.

For Example

```
string customValue = string.Empty;
string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
appData = Path.Combine(appData, "MyAppName");
if(!Directory.Exists(appData))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appData);
string appDataFile = Path.Combine(appData, "MyAppNameSettings.txt");
if(File.Exists(appDataFile))
    customValue = File.ReadAllText(appDataFile);
else
{
    customValue = AskUserForTheFirstTimeValue();
    File.WriteAllText(appDataFile, customValue);
}
```

The file is stored in a subfolder of the common application data (C:\programdata) created to store your data files. You check if the file exists at first launch. If the file exists you read its content (assumed to be a simple string here), if the file doesn't exist then you ask the input and store the value for the successive runs of your app.

Comment: thank you bro. if i use the txt file as a embedded resource then?

Comment: Not really necessary. If you have a default value you could easily change the above approach setting the customValue to your default. Otherwise I can't see any reason to use an embedded resource for this.

Comment: ohk i got it but what about the launching form1 only at 1st time?

Comment: Move the code that writes the file inside the form1 and launch it instead of AskUserForTheFirstTimeValue example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Registry Key in Windows Registry (regedit), and when you start your program verify if its exists and the value.

Link about Registry Keys:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: storing values in application configuration file is more reliable than storing in registry as some useres may not have permissions to read/write values in or from registry IMO.

Comment: Mine is just an opinion and perhaps your answer is correct, but leaving user programs mess with registry has been a terrible mistake by Microsoft. Nowadays there are better options (config files, xml, a plain file are all better options)

Comment: @Steve: sidenote, apart from `registry` and `config files` is there any other better approach to tackle these kind of problems.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I usually opt for a custom XML file saved in the ProgramData folder or User personal application folder (depending on the kind of settings of course)

Comment: and i see many thirdparty widows applications relay on windows `registry`( pleae correct me. if i'm wrong), if there are more settings to save. how they handle the issues with User access permissions and things like that?

Comment: lol, downvote my answer? Its a correct answer you can not downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a settings file that keeps a variable like `IsFirstRun = true;` This application should be distributed and compiled with this file, at start up you should read this file and if you encounter the true state you should load the appropriate forms. You should also ensure that the value is immediately set to false for the second launch condition.

have a look at .net's setting class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can suggest:

## First one

### Use the application configuration file:

Creating such file in c# is pretty easy, per usual if you start with a standard `Windows Forms Project Template` you will most likely already have an `app.config` in that project, if not, follow instructions from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx) (under `Application Configuration Files`).

Add a simple boolean value to the file like so (that `appSettings-node` is created under the root `configuration-node`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="FirstRun" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
```

In your first form, where you do your application configuration you add code to manipulate your `app.config` programmatically using the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)-Class for the event that configuration has been finished and can be saved (probably some button click, note that you will need a Reference to `System.Configuration`):

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

bool myVal = bool.Parse(config.AppSettings.Settings["FirstRun"].Value);

if (myVal)
{
    // MessageBox.Show("yep, its true");

    config.AppSettings.Settings["FirstRun"].Value = false.ToString();
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
else
{
    // MessageBox.Show("na, its not true anymore.");
}
```

## Second one

### Use a property grid for your application configuration:

Since from your description it seems you only use the first form to enter some application configuration values, I would recommend using the [PropertyGrid-Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/aa302326.aspx) for that.

That control can be easily bound to an object that exposes some properties (what a surprise) that are then used to render a standardized control containing captions and value selection controls dependend on the property's types, for example:

```
public class Settings
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you check at your program start, whether the configuration file (you define the path) exists, and if so, try to deserialize an object from its xml (sample below works for primitive types, for more complex ones you might have to extend the serializer, but you get the idea).

That serialized object represents your saved application settings, so you do not need to open up the propertygrid-form anymore.

If no file could be found the grid gets initialized with a simple new constructed object and you show that form:

this goes into your initialization code:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("SaveHere.xml");
if (file.Exists)
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("SaveHere.xml"))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
        Settings mySettings = (Settings)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
}
else
{
    this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Settings();
    // show form code
}
```

this code goes into the event code where you want to save your configuration

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("SaveHere.xml",false))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(writer, this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much but there is one more thing that after 1st time the variable value which where sated 1st time should load directly to form 2

Comment: @user3289174 you have that saved in a file then, when using the first approach, you can read your saved values (in your second form) from `config.AppSettings.Settings["<YourValueIdentifier>"].Value` when using the second approach you just deserialize your xml-file to an object (in your second form) `Settings mySettings = (Settings)serializer.Deserialize(reader);` your settings then are inside that very object `mySettings` or did I misunderstand you