# IIS Locking possibly causing ASP.NET project to throw HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I'm fairly new to .NET framework. I'm trying to run an application copied from another system running visual studio 2010 on my own system. I am also running Visual Studio 2010. When I press F5 to build and run, I get the following error messages

[image]

On the output:

```
------ Build started: Project: cloudintegra.dal, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  cloudintegra.dal -> D:\Users\Chibuzo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\cloudintegra\cloudintegra.dal\bin\Debug\cloudintegra.dal.dll
------ Build started: Project: cloudintegra.ui, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
  cloudintegra.ui -> D:\Users\Chibuzo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\cloudintegra\cloudintegra.ui\bin\cloudintegra.dll
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Also when I select view on browser on a special .aspx file, get the following Internal Server Error [image]

Please how can I resolve this issue?

Here is the root Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="dbcloudintegraConnectionStringb" connectionString="Data Source=PROGRAMOS-PC\INST1;Initial Catalog=dbcloudintegra;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="dbcloudintegraConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PROGRAMOS-PC\INST1;Initial Catalog=prom_temprary;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <location path="default.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="user,admin"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
                <deny users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="__upload.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="user,admin"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
                <deny users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="_cs" value="dbcloudintegraConnectionString"/>
        <add key="fileuploads" value="D:\Users\Chibuzo\Documents\prog_fileuploads\"/>
        <add key="errorlogs" value="D:\Users\Chibuzo\Documents\prog_errorlogs\"/>
        <add key="enableLogOn" value="true"/>
        <add key="enableRecaptcha" value="false"/>
        <add key="domainAdminDays" value="5000"/>
        <add key="domainPath" value="http://www.prominentetrade.com/"/>
        <add key="recaptchaPublicKey" value="6LcZkvESAAAAAOWvWUtykUEoIGnU_qLiJlAvUN9e"/>
        <add key="recaptchaPrivateKey" value="6LcZkvESAAAAAIBTKFXnqZHe_bqFLkwjtZfcgqoV"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState cookieName="__CIP.SSID" timeout="20"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
        </customErrors>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/datepicker.ascx" tagName="datepicker"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/customersearch.ascx" tagName="customersearch"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/generalledgersearch.ascx" tagName="generalledgersearch"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/staffsearch.ascx" tagName="staffsearch"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/securitysearch.ascx" tagName="securitysearch"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/alert.ascx" tagName="alert"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/sidebar.ascx" tagName="sidebar"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/tools.ascx" tagName="tools"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/equitytrader.ascx" tagName="equitytrader"/>
                <add tagPrefix="cloudintegra" src="~/controls/marketdata.ascx" tagName="marketdata"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
            <codeSubDirectories>
                <add directoryName="VB"/>
            </codeSubDirectories>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="__AUTH.PCI" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="20"/>
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="dbcloudintegraConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="cloudintegra" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="dbcloudintegraConnectionString" applicationName="cloudintegra"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add connectionStringName="dbcloudintegraConnectionString" applicationName="cloudintegra" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
                <add applicationName="cloudintegra" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <!--<add name="HttpGet"/>-->
                <add name="HttpPost"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <!--<httpModules>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </httpModules>-->
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
        </handlers>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.net>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using crystal reports into your project. For that you need to install crystal report runtime.

Check following post, it will resolve your issue. 
[CrystalImageHandler.aspx not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357854/crystalimagehandler-aspx-not-found)

Comment: I've installed crystal reports. The build error is gone, but the Internal server error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Again, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135217/594832) check that there isn't any configuration at a parent-level, that causes the conflict.

Based on the error message the `<handlers`-section can't be accessed. So check any possible parent web.config or even the applicationhost.config located here: D:\Users\Chibuzo\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

The relevant entry should look like this:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
```

Comment: Yes, I've found the entry in applicationhost.config. But I don't know what to do there. Here is what it looks like.
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
            <add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
            <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>