# How to retrieve a connection string from web.config?

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string

How can we retrieve connection string information from web.config file? I am unable to write the code for it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13043569/453277 and many other questions. Your question is likely to be closed unless you show some research effort and you show how those existing answers do not address your question.

Answer (score 2):

Import System.Configuration into your project.

then

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method of a string and call the string in your web.config file

```
private string Get_ConnectionString
{
  return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NAME OF STRING"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ConfigurationManager` class you can read settings in *web.config* and *app.config*.

This class have a property called `ConnectionStrings` which gets the *ConnectionStringsSection* data for the current application's default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add System.Configuration as a reference:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XYZ"].ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned Web.config, i assumed its for a web project.
You need to add reference to System.Configuration namespace to your web project

```
static internal string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnection"].ConnectionString;
```