# C# Windows Service - How to read from ini file or app.config?

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config, ini

I have one Windows Polling Service to send an automatic email each 10 minutes. I use `Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));` to sleep the thread for 10 minutes, which is hard coded right now.

To avoid hard coding, I have tried `app.config` which was not successful. I want to move the hard coding to some `.ini` files. How can I read `.ini` file from C# Windows Service.

I try the below code to read from my windows service:

```
string pollingInterval = (string)new AppSettingsReader().GetValue("PollingInterval", typeof(string));
```

Gives the below error:

> `Configuration system failed to initialize`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file)

Comment: "I have tried `App.config` which was not successful." - why and how was it "not successful"? That would usually be the preferred way to store information like that. Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043530/what-is-app-config-in-c-net-how-to-use-it ?

Comment: What's the issue with using a App.config? Side note: Your task sounds like it could be simply solved by running a console application from Windows Task Scheduler rather than running an idling Windows Service.

Answer (score 11):

`app.config` is better solution than INI file.

Your `app.config` file look something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
.......
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TimerInterval" value="10" />
  </appSettings>
.......
</configuration>
```

And you read it like:

```
int timerInterval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerInterval"]);
```

You need to import namespace `using System.Configuration;` and add reference to System.Configuration dll.

Answer (score 5):

Using App.config is as simple as

```
string interval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["interval"];

TimeSpan t;
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(interval, @"h\:m\:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out t);
```

(Don't forget to add the reference `System.Configuration` assembly and `using System.Configuration` + `System.Globalization`)

Your App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="interval" value="00:10:00" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```