# Unity Container - Register a singleton "Int32"

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

All I want to do is (in an app.config) define a singleton 'Int32'. The idea is that it will be a named registration, and used as a parameter in multiple other type definitions - meaning the actual int value itself only needs to be defined once (and reducing manual error).

Something along the lines of the following...

```
  <register type="int" name="MyInt">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
    <constructor>
      <param name="value" value="23"/>          
    </constructor>
  </register>
```

Now I realise the Int32 structure doesn't have such a constructor, but what I am requesting seems so simple that I cant believe it cant be done.

Am I missing something obvious?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify a single instance:

```xml
<container>
  <instance name="FooBar" type="System.Int32" value="123" />
</container>
```

Which is resolved like so:

```cs
int value = container.Resolve<int>("FooBar");
```

If you would require to construct another type from configuration, it would be like so:

```xml
<!-- "SomeType" is a type here, but you can have any mapping here -->
<register type="SomeType">
  <constructor>
    <!-- "value" is the name of the constructor argument -->
    <param name="value" dependencyName="FooBar" />
  </constructor>
</register>
```

Comment: Superb. Exactly what I was after. Not exactly clear in the Microsoft documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Can you change behavior from Dependency injection to reading config file?
[Here good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043530/what-is-app-config-in-c-net-how-to-use-it) how you can put int value to config file and read it without DI.

Second solution: you can wrap your int value into simple object with singl property and necessary constructor.

Comment: First option is out as trying to keep it all DI. I already have the latter suggestion implemented (small wrapper object), but it seems a bit clunky - hence this question!

Comment: May you use first solution? It allow change value from from app.config and use it value wherever in your code.

Comment: There is strong typed configuration, but this solution need some code. Here you can find description how you can made it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx