# How to correctly read values from a Text File

Tags: c#, json, text, uwp

I am working on a project where values are stored in a Text file and should be retrieved every time the application starts.
The text file is very simple and straight forward:

```
{
    "HowManyDayImages": "11",
    "HowManyNightImages": "5",
}
```

I have this simple class with two values as numbers:

```
public class ImageConfig
{
    public int HowManyDayImages { get; set; }
    public int HowManyNightImages { get; set; }
}
```

then I have this code to look up the respected file and read the values from it and set them:

```
public static async void LoadConfigAsync()
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationDataContainer settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        string themeName = (string)settings.Values["Theme"];
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFolder timeFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync("Dynamic");
        StorageFolder themeFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync(themeName);
        string imageConf;
        if (File.Exists("images.conf"))
        {
            imageConf = File.ReadAllText("images.conf");
        }
        else
        {
            imageConf = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.imageConf);
        }
        imageSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImageConfig>(imageConf);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

with this I am facing two problems. the first is that in this line " Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.imageConf);" I am getting the error that "Properties" does not exist in the current context.

[image: The Dynamic folder inside the project]

The second problem I am facing is that I keep getting an error saying that "Dynamic" could not be found.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using appconfig/webconfig?

Comment: Well I am just starting to learn. to me it seemed a bit easier using local settings. I am trying to work out the appconfig, and if it worked out I will start using it

Comment: This is what you get by copy/pasting any code found on internet. Take a step-by-step tutorial to learn everything from beginning.

Comment: @AsemKhen, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043530/what-is-app-config-in-c-net-how-to-use-it. It's a way to read text setting's from a file, at run time, that's an industry standard that's been tried and tested. No need to re-invent the wheel!

Comment: @WynDiesel, App.config seems to be really helpful to store application settings within the apps directory. What I am trying to reach is reading an external configuration files bundled in folders that can be added or deleted.
( The app looks up a Zip file, extracts it to an internal folder and reads the configuration within it to set the previously mentioned values )

Comment: @AsemKhen I think Wyn was referring to the use of Properties to hold the name of the file, as opposed to storing the filename in app.config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to correctly read values from a Text File

**First** you need a text file that stored json info, then store it in specified folder that you could access next time.

*Create text file*

```
// Create sample file; replace if exists.
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile =
    await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt",
        Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

*Write text to file*

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile =
    await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");

await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "json info");
```

**Second** load the text from the text file, then use `JsonConvert` to deserialize the text.

*Reading from a file*

```
string json = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);

var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json);
```

**Third** load the setting from `DeserializeObject` that get from the above step.

```
var info = item.info;
```

**Note**

> The second problem I am facing is that I keep getting an error saying that "Dynamic" could not be found.

From you screen shot, the `Dynamic` folder stored under your project directory, you could not use [`LocalFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) to get it. Please use package [`InstalledLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation).

```
var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Dyanmic");
```