# How do i get a specific value from the config file

Tags: asp.net, app-config

Hi i have got the following `app.config`.
 How do i get the values for smtp server mail subject etc.

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"]; i'm getting nothing
```

actually added key values also the output returned null.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043530/what-is-app-config-in-c-net-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple

1st You set **web.config or app.config** file value like this.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="SmtpServer" value="abc" />
</appSettings>
```

then get value.

```
string filePath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"]);
```

**Or** 
Same as app.config file

```
 string filePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"];
```