# Retrieve connection string in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, connection-string

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) example to understand how to use a DataGridView component can be used to display and manipulate a database table.

I have configured the database access through a Data Connection using Tools->Connect to Database menu in Visual Studio 2017.

[image: Data Connections]

Now I am trying to get the Sqlconnection using the name of that connection configured through the Visual Studio, but I do not know if I need to hardcode the connection string or it shall be retrieved from the configuration.

I have tried this:

```
Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("localhost(wildfire)").ConnectionString)
```

and this:

```
Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("wildfire").ConnectionString)
```

In both cases I get:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned Nothing.
```

What shall I do to get the connection string? Do I need to hardcode it in the source code?

Note: I tag the question also in C# in case the answer is similar. I can convert the syntax from C# to VB if the way to retrieve the connection string is similar.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the Data Connection in the server explorer you can obtain the connection string by pressing the F4 button to view the properties.  You'll see a Connection String property.  The next step is copy that string and set it into your app.config.  If you're unsure how to do that read the following answers to this question...

[What is App.config in C#.NET? How to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043530/what-is-app-config-in-c-net-how-to-use-it)