# What is the location of a file 'config.ini' in C# ?

Tags: c#

The code below creates the file "config.ini" with the values used by the User when the app is closed.

```
        void Form1_FormClosing(object sender,FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
        IniFile ini=new IniFile(Application.StartupPath+@"\\config.ini");
```

When running the app in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, the file config.ini will be saved in the app directory\bin\Debug.

By publish, install and run the app, I can not find the file config.ini.

What is the location of the file config.ini?

Thanks in advanced,
ocaccy

Answer (score 1):

The [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) point to the location where the .exe of your application is located. Your .ini file should be there.

However, using .ini files is considered a bit outdated, a better approach (and built-in in .net) is using application configuration files ([app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431742/what-is-app-config-for) for WinForms)

Comment: Thank you. I'm using the app.config for windows. Project/Properties/Settings.... Where is the file located? Sometimes, the user need to delete this data outside of the application and start from the beginning. We can do that?

Comment: When deployed, the config file is in the folder the .exe is in, and has the name <exename>.exe.config

Comment: Thank you, I found this file but I can't reset the data out of the app.

Comment: Thank you. We solved the problem by redirecting the file to a location with easy access to the User.Like this:    
    IniFile ini=new IniFile("F:\\Xconfig.ini");