# Business logic shared by ASP.NET / WinForms: find the location of the assembly to access relative files to it

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, winforms, configuration-files

I'm in the midst of refactoring some 'inherited' business logic code that for the ASP.NET side needs to be initialized with an absolute path, but on the WinForms / WPF side only with a relative path to a [GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) directory.

I want to merge these two into a relative setting stored in [Web.config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config) or [App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431742/what-is-app-config-for) so I can do [xcopy deployment](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/03/make-mine-xcopy.html) of both without having to hard-code path names.

Which ways are there to find the location of an assembly and the relative files deployed with it, without it having to depend on the ASP.NET specific [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) or [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a path relative to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

This will be the directory containing the executable for a client app, and the web site root directory for ASP.NET.