# oledb can't connect

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Want to connect to a .mdb file in the App_Data folder.

Connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source=|App_Data|\\abcd.mdb"
```

Receive error:

```
Not a valid file name.
```

When adapter tries to fill the dataset.

Tried foreslash, backslash, squiggly line, you name it. Nothing seems to work.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Well I am afraid `Jackery Xu` you will need to show more code than that.. also your connection string looks a bit off

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access what about just one backslash ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little too late but I had the same issue as you questioned here and this is what worked for me:

```
string con = String.Format(
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=True;", 
         String.Format(
                @"{0}\{1}",
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
                "abcd.accdb"
         )
);
```

The `@` enables you to use characters like `\` without backslashing these. I always use `@` when entering filepaths. Although I can imagine that hard-coding filepaths in your code is probably not the best way to do it, try this instead ([What is app.config for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431742/what-is-app-config-for)).

The line `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` resolves to the value of the environment variable `%APPDATA%`.

Also note that this solution is for `accdb` files and if you want to use this for `mdb` you need to change the `Provider` to `Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0`.

I hope this answer helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think it you should use `|DataDirectory|`, not `|App_Data|`. And a single backslash after it.